# How do I handle the loading of the correct iframe using Cypress?

Tags: iframe, cypress

I am using Cypress to write e2e automation tests for a web application containing iframes. The web application contains multiple hidden iframes. After I log into the application, Cypress does not display the correct iframe. Instead, it displays a hidden iframe. Is there any way to handle the iframe selection by Cypress?

Most of the questions were related to targeting elements inside iframes. I found no questions related to loading of webpages using iframes.

EDIT:
Please note: My issue is not related to https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136

Answer (score 0):

> I here official information about iframe issue :

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/known-issues.html#Iframes

> Copied and paste :

You cannot target elements or interact with anything in an iframe - regardless of it being a same domain or cross domain iframe.

This is actively being worked on in Cypress and you’ll first see support for same domain iframes, followed by cross domain (they are much harder to do).

> Issue URLs :

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136

Comment: So, will Cypress not even load pages containing iframes? I thought only interacting with elements containing iframes is not possible (although there are some workarounds).

Comment: @Shaw I think there are few users also having similar issue  following URLs : https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136